# GitHub Cloning gives "file name too long"

Tags: github, filenames

When I clone my repository via GitHub Desktop it throws error that there is a file which name is too long ,I know that the file limit is 255 and I disabled it from regedit and from policy editor but the problem still occurs and i dont know what to do

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For anyone who is wondering how to fix this I found a way!
Go to your GitHub Desktop Folder -> app -> resources -> app -> git -> mingw64 -> etc -> gitconfig , and there under [core] section add this field "longpaths = true" :)

Comment: +This problem happen every time when you update GitHub Desktop!

Comment: Had the same problem with Fork 
If I run the command.. "git config --system core.longpaths true" in a command prompt it doesn't help in Fork, because Fork (like other git tools?) use a "bundled" git, not the one you might have downloaded separate. 
Solution >> add "longpaths=true" to core section as described above>>

C:\Users\[---YOU-- ]\AppData\Local\Fork\gitInstance\2.20.1\mingw64\etc\gitconfig

(on windows 10)

Comment: The filepath I used was C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-2.8.0\resources\app\git\etc

The git shell command as mentioned in other answers didn't work

Comment: In git bash write the command: 

    git config --global core.longpaths true

https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/8023

Comment: Thanks for this and also thanks choba78 for the file path. Way easier to find where it was following your path!

Answer (score 9):

Go to your GitHub Desktop Folder -> app -> resources -> app -> git -> etc -> gitconfig

And there under [core] section add this field "**longpaths = true**"

For My case:

Path Is:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-3.0.7\resources\app\git\etc
```

And updated file (gitconfig) format:

```
[core]
    symlinks = false
    autocrlf = true
    fscache = true
    longpaths = true
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to **GitHubDesktop Folder** (located in AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop) > app > resources > app > git > etc > **gitconfig**

```
C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-3.1.6\resources\app\git\etc
```

Open '**gitconfig**' with any program that works (I opened it with Windows NotePad) and add "`longpaths = true`" in the [core] section

[image: gitconfig "longpaths = true"]

Then save the file. Open GitHub Desktop again and it will work:)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GitHub Desktop and facing "file name too long" issue while check-in the code. Apply following solution it works.
Go to - **Repository-> Show in Explorer -> .git**  Edit **config** file with any editor(eg- Notepad++) - under [core] section add this field **"longpaths = true"**

**[core]
longpaths = true**